# Connect Camel with EventHubs using Kafka protocol

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, azure-eventhub

I am trying to route messages from Camel to Azure EventHubs.
EventHubs namespace was created using Kafka enabled flag.

```
         String eventHubsPassword = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule " +
        "required username=\"$ConnectionString\" " + 
        "password=\"<Connection String>\";";

        String eventHubsConfig = 
        "&requestTimeoutMs=30000" +
        "&securityProtocol=SASL_SSL" + 
        "&saslMechanism=PLAIN" +
        "&saslJaasConfig=" + eventHubsPassword;

        from(component + ":queue:" + queue )
        .to("kafka:mock-topic?brokers=" + eventHubsKafkaBrokers + eventHubsConfig)
```

where `mock-topic` is the name of event hub, `eventHubsKafkaBrokers` is like `mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net:9093` and `<connection string>` is the connection string of the event hub namespace.

So I get this log

```
2019-07-03 23:35:23 INFO  AbstractLogin:53 - Successfully logged in.
2019-07-03 23:35:23 INFO  AppInfoParser:109 - Kafka version : 1.0.0
```

On sending the message I get

```
2019-07-03 23:37:51 WARN  NetworkClient:241 - [Producer clientId=producer-2] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

What could be wrong? Camel version is `2.21.1`. Doesn't camel support `SASL_SSL` security protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps anybody, I ended up using the amqp support provided by EventHubs. Put the destination of the route to defined amqp component then.

`AMQPComponent authorizedAmqp = AMQPComponent.amqpComponent(
                eventHubsNamespace,
                eventHubsUsername,   //Shared access policy name
                eventHubsPassword);  //Secret code for this shared access policy
        main.bind("amqps", authorizedAmqp);
...
from('jms://source")
.to("amqps" + ":queue:" + eventhubInstance);`